# Bitcoin wallet for Symbian operating system?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Can I use Bitcoin on my Nokia N97 phone which uses Symbian OS?

I cannot find any Bitcoin wallet applications on [Ovi store](http://store.ovi.com) :-(

I have found a wallet client for the Android operating system but that is hard to install on my N97.

I'm willing to compile a client from sources, but I can't find any. I've tried SourceForge but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a client for Symbian? No. Could you cross-compile one? Very unlikely; the Android SDK has commands written for Android. What do you mean, "hard to install"? Can you install it?

Comment: According to this http://androidforums.com/other-phones-android-non-android/289734-can-i-have-android-my-nokia-n97.html attempting a cross-compile of Android to an N97 is a non-starter.

Answer (score 3):

**CuteCoin might help**

There is a project in GitHub that apparently provides a Symbian3 Bitcoin client using InstaWallet. See https://github.com/Matoking/cuteCoin for source code.

There is also some supporting discussion about Symbian on the forums here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=26154.0

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

Use a web client, such as [MyWallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet) or [StrongCoin](https://strongcoin.com/).

Comment: _(technically my suggestion would be "buy a phone with a real OS", but I guess that wasn't exactly what you were asking for)_